# New emojis don't show on Mac, only on iPhone

Tags: macos, messages, emoji

The new emojis don't appear as a valid character. They appear as a rectangle in Messages on my Mac. On the iPhone I can see the emoji fine.

My software is 10.10.5. How can I download the new emojis on mac?

This Emoji appears on my phone but not on my Mac:

[image]

Comment: Your Question is not specific. What emoji character? What version of iOS? What version of Mac OS X? What apps?

Comment: One everyone missed - What Mac, how old? It might be "up to date" but if it's an old enough machine, that could be because it cannot run anything newer.

Comment: It's a mid 2012 mac.

Comment: Version 10.10.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [Mac OS X 10.11.1](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1845) (El Capitan) on your Mac to see the new emojis.

Comment: Can you fix your hyperlink?

Answer (score 0):

are you upgraded to the latest ios and osx versions? if you text those emojis to people not upgraded, they will see the boxes.